# Inner div set to 100% overflows

Tags: css, html

I have an outer DIV that is `position: fixed`  and is set as an overlay, inside that is another div that I have set to `100%` with a margin of `30px` to give it the appearance of an inner border frame. Unfortunately, **the border to the right and bottom flow off the screen**. Any advice / hints would be appreciated. Thanks,

---

What I have: http://jsfiddle.net/DTse2/1/

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to this css

```
#overlay {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right:0;bottom:0;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        -moz-opacity:1;
        -khtml-opacity: 1;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 10000;padding:30px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #overlay_inner {
        border: 1px solid #adadad;
    height:100%;


    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/DTse2/2/)**